# Filtering after a join in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables( `location` and `country` ) that am trying to query; which are represented by the models below in my flask application

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, ForeignKey, Integer, \
                       Numeric, SmallInteger, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.schema import FetchedValue
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'country'

    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    full_country_name = db.Column(db.String(90), nullable=False)
    country_code = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.country_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Country %r>' % self.country_name


class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'location'

    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_name = db.Column(db.String(75), nullable=False)
    country_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('mashamba.country.country_id'), nullable=False, index=True)

    country = db.relationship('Country', primaryjoin='Location.country_id == Country.country_id', backref='locations')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.location_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Location %r>' % self.location_name
```

What am trying to do is get all columns from both tables by performing a join using the following code

```
Location.query.join(Country).\
                filter_by(location_name='Cairo',
                          country_id=67).first()
```

Problem is when i run the code i get the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'app.models.Country'>' has no property 'location_name'
```

Everything works fine when you run for example this code

```
Location.query.join(Country).all()
```

What is wrong here and how can this be solved?

Comment: I don't have Flask-SQLAlchemy at hand, but I think you need to switch to `filter` instead of `filter_by` here so you can distinguish, like so: `filter(Location.location_name == 'Cairo', Country.country_id == 67)`

Comment: Side note: it's unusual to scope the names twice as you have done. Just write `Location.id` rather than `Location.location_id`

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist Thank you for that it worked very well

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That "double scoping" is actually a very handy practice. It often allows using `USING` in joins, or even `NATURAL JOIN`, if having to write raw SQL. It's also a lot easier to recognize what's what in large queries, if not using dotted identifiers, or using generated aliases. It also helps in Python: if you pass the wrong type of object to a function, it'll blow up early, when trying to access for example `location_id`. If all DB objects share `id` as primary key, you'll possibly be none the wiser.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`filter_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) applies to the primary entity of the query, or *the last entity that was the target of a [`join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join)*. In your case that is `Country`, which does not have the required attribute. Either use [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) or move the call to `filter_by(location_name=...)` before the join:

```
Location.query.\
    filter_by(location_name='Cairo').\
    join(Country).\
    filter_by(country_id=67).\
    first()
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i tested your code and it works fine as well