# is there a way to concatenate querys with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

HotelInfo:

```
    class HotelInfo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'hotel_info'
    country_area = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    hotel_id = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    hotel_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    hotel_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    hotel_address = db.Column(db.Text)
    review_score = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    review_qty = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    clean = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    comf = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    loct = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    fclt = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    staff = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    vfm = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    wifi = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    reviews = db.relationship('HotelReview', backref='hotel_info', lazy=True)
```

And HotelReview:

```
class HotelReview(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'hotel_reviews'
    uuid = (db.Column(db.String, nullable=True, primary_key=True))
    hotel_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('hotel_info.hotel_id'))
    review_title = db.Column(db.Text)
    review_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    review_score = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    review_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    reviewer_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    hash_reviewer_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    reviewer_location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    posting_conts = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    positive_content = db.Column(db.Text)
    negative_content = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n1 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n2 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n3 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n4 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n5 = db.Column(db.Text)
    staydate = db.Column(db.Text)
```

I'm trying to get hotels with more than 5 reviews, and the reviews from those hotels between 2 dates.

I have this for the moment:

This is for getting the hotels with more than 5 reviews

```
Hotels = HotelInfo.query.filter(HotelInfo.review_qty >= 5)
```

I know with that I can get the all the reviews from an specific hotel with `hotel[0].reviews` for example, but I want keep only the most recent reviews.

I have this for get only the most recent reviews:

```
reviews = HotelReview.review_date.between('2018-01-01', '2019-12-31')
```

But don't have idea to do all together with one query.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a single query? I don't think it's even possible. Think about how it might look in a SQL language

Comment: @grbvirus74 yes i think its possible...it will be somthing like that in sql

```SELECT * FROM hotel_info INNER JOIN hotel_reviews ON hotel_reviews.hotel_id = hotel_info.hotel_id WHERE hotel_reviews.review_date BETWEEN ('2018-01-01') AND ('2019-12-012')```
Is'nt correct?

Comment: @AdamWist but then you have only `HotelInfo` without reviews

Comment: But Inner Join dont put the tables together??

Comment: @Nishant If OP uses `Hotel.reviews` then SQLAlchemy will make another call to the database to fetch the reviews.

Comment: no it doesn't. It just links those two tables by their keys.

Comment: @gribvirus74 So...how can i do it??

Comment: That's the catch - you can't. You need two queries for that

Comment: You can always use a `JOIN `in SQlALchemy right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044309/sqlalchemy-how-to-join-several-tables-by-one-query. I don't know if you can do this in a clean `ORM` like syntax, worth thinking!

Comment: Seems already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862572/filtering-after-a-join-in-flask-sqlalchemy/51863204